# change property of button under certain condition

Tags: php, session, button

I'm trying to do this with PHP only.

I have html buttons connected to an PHP array.

The array's arranged like this:

```
$board=array(
array("w","",""),
array("","","w"),
array("w","","")
);
```

I use a for loop to assign position of array to variables. 
something like this:

```
$i=0;
for ($row=0;$row<3;$row++){
fop($column=0;$column<3;$column++){
$("b".$i)=$board[$row][$column];
$i++}}
```

this creates, for example,  $b0=$board[0][0].

On the html side, 
I have buttons that are also named like "b0". 
Something will print if these buttons are pressed, and has a "w" assigned to its corresponding position in the array:

```
for($e=0;$e<9;$e++){
  if(isset($_POST["b$e"])){  /*this is the button on html*/
    if($("b".$e")=="w"){     /*this represents array positions*/
       print "assigned"}
       }}
```

It prints "assigned" if "w" exists in array position(tested,it works)

What I am trying to do from this point, is to either change button value to "hit" 
or to change its font color without refreshing every time.

Say that I click a button and it has "w" assigned.
I want it to change property WITHOUT wiping out other buttons that went through property change.
(Something like, keeping all button properties in Session, if thats possible..)

So, I don't want a whole new set of buttons to display every time a submit button is pressed, 
but rather to change that button ONLY. 
 [button][button][button] to [button][green button][button]...somethin like that.

Comment: You cannot do that without a refresh when limiting yourself to php only. You do need client side scripting for that, so javascript.

Comment: I came to success by keeping button styles to session variables!

Comment: Sure, you can "remember" stuff that way, but that still means you have to refresh the page, no other way to change the buttons by means of php. In the question you wrote that you do _not_ accept a page refresh for that. But maybe I got that wrong. Great you found a solution for you.

Comment: it would have been easier if i just use javascript though(to change button colors), but I guess for the reason that the page jumps to PHP under POST/GET method, the page wouldn't keep the color changed buttons(if i used javascript to change color by onclick and call function). I think they should let you keep javasript setting even if you jump from a html form to a PHP page...would've been much easier, anyways

Comment: Certainly that is possible. Using ajax requests you can relay that information from client to server in background, whilst doing the optical change directly on the client side. That way all information you require is present on the server side at all times.

Comment: if you don't mind, can you give me an example of using ajax to do that?

Comment: Sorry, the internet is full of examples for short routines sending some value to a server. Just send the button action (new value/color) in such a GET request, store it into the session on the server side and it is available for the next full reload via PHP.

Comment: Well, thats what I originally did. (style/value set to php variable, if meet requirement, $var="color:red" etc hen store this to a session and plug it back to $var i session isset) I was hoping there's an alternative to this method, like using javascript/ajax requests, as you have mentioned.

Comment: Let's say _it does make sense_. You don't have to. Indeed, with your approach you can keep all such details in the request in form of parameters. But in the end that is nothing else but a session, just less elegant. Using a session is really simple and makes your code easier to understand and maintain.